# Erro "O nome "InitializeComponent" não existe no contexto atual" em todo projeto Xamarin.forms que crio

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin-forms

Do nada, TODOS meus projetos estão dando o erro

> O nome "InitializeComponent" não existe no contexto atual (CS0103)

Ao serem criados. Não preciso alterar nada, o erro vem de graça.

Pelo que pesquisei, tentei consertar limpando a solução, recuperando pacotes nuget e recompilando, mas não está dando em nada!

Imagem do erro:

[image]

O que posso fazer?

Comment: Do nada ou relacionado à sua pergunta anterior?

Comment: Acredito que não tenha a ver com minha pergunta anterior porque eu iniciei um projeto novo e em outro diretório. Mas sim, passou a acontecer depois do que houve em minha pergunta anterior. O que está funcionando pra mim é dar ctrl c ctrl v na pasta de um outro projeto vazio que tenho aqui que não está gerando erro algum, mas se eu de fato for no VS e criar um novo projeto, esse erro em questão acontece.

Comment: Crie um novo projeto e veja se aparece algum erro na aba error list

Comment: Novo projeto criado agora: https://i.imgur.com/4YlgqhF.png

Comment: Como estão os seus xaml? Nas propriedades do Build action, estão como embeded ou compile? Como está criando o projeto, Shared ou .Net Standard?

Comment: Desculpe, como/onde checo as propriedades de build action?

Comment: Se você clicar com o botão direito em cima do arquivo XAML aparece a opção "Run Custom Tool"?

Comment: Se está se referindo a isso: https://i.imgur.com/djZLGDY.png, então não...

Comment: Bem, fui em propriedades do MainPage.xaml, troquei a Ação de Compilação para Compilador C# e depois voltei pra Recurso Inserido e o erro sumiu. Recompilei pra ter certeza e realmente sumiu... Estou confuso.

Comment: Testei o que fiz acima com todos os outros projetos que estavam bugados e deu certo.

Answer (score 0):

Problema deve ser o Xamarin.forms, tens de desatualizar o nuget do xamarin.forms. Normalmente, quando existe novos updates o meu projeto tem o mesmo erro. Consigo resolver desatualizar o xamarin.forms para a versão anterior  e reabrir o projeto.

Comment: Nos 2 últimos comentários acima eu fiz um procedimento estranho que resolveu...

Comment: Ok. Mas se tiver outra vez o mesmo problema. Experimente que maioria das vezes é esse o problema e é mais rápido.